# Pressing any key in firefox repeats a string (under load)

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, firefox

On 32-bit lubuntu (14.10) with firefox 35.0.1, occasionally while browsing a very, very strange bug with text input will occur.

When typing into any text box, any key will input, instead of the character associated with that key, one character in a string. The next key press will input the next character in that string, and it will repeat. For example, just recently any key press would enter characters from the string {null, null, null, null, a} and then repeat. Even backspace, enter, etc would do this. This appears to happen mostly under load (when there's a greedy applet on a page, for example).

As far as I'm aware, the settings for my keyboard and input system are at defaults. This is only affecting firefox, input to any other programs works fine.q

Now the problem is happening with the q key. The following text is what happens when I type the alphabet.

abcdefqjklmnopqtuvwxyz

The test load was supplied by http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/GeoGebraCalculus/derivative_intuitive_chain_rule.html which is where I more recently noticed the problem could be reproduced at.

To reproduce: Go to the site listed above, let the interactive example run for a minute or so, open another tab and attempt to type into the address bar. On my Dell Latitude D630 (old potato) with core 2 duo at 2.0 GHz, it will cause some of the text you type to begin repeating whenever any key is pressed (instead of whatever the key would normally do).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Unfortunately there is not much more we can do for you here on AskUbuntu except telling you that you should file this as a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi.